# cannot reshape array of size 85696 into shape (85696,1,256,256)

Tags: python, image, numpy, scikit-learn

The number of images is 107121 which are divided into test and train.

X_train = 85696

In this, I have to just add depth to the image so that further it can go to the CNN model but during reshaping,

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1,256, 256)

I am getting this error:

cannot reshape an array of size 85696 into shape (85696,1,256,256)

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1,img_rows, img_cols)
```

Comment: What is the output of print(X_train.shape)? What is the purpose of reshaping?

Comment: `reshape` cannot change the total number of elements.  What's the shape of `X_train` and what's its `dtype`.

Comment: the output of X_train.shape is (85696,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total number of elements on the LHS & RHS should be the same while applying the `reshape` function. In your case, the total number of elements on the RHS is `85696*1*256*256 = 5616173056`, while that on the LHS is `85696`.

Doing something like `X_train = 85696` to `X_train = X_train.reshape(21424, 1, 2, 2)` is perfectly fine, as the total number of elements are now equal.

Hope this helps!!